# how to solve this error when I run npm start in node.js

Tags: node.js, npm-start

When I run the `npm start` command, I get this error.

I had the latest version of npm installed but now I have installed an older one because the project is old and uses an older version of npm.this is my folder structure and my packag.json.
`Here is an Error message`
[image]

Here is my `file`

[image][image]

Comment: I guess you need to install `module` first  by typing command `npm install`

Comment: i did this , i run npm install

Comment: Is it fixed, can you share the code repository

Comment: no it is not fixed , i can't share the code repository of git because it is private ,with the team.

Comment: can you show us your package.json script part and your folder structure?it seems error is coz you don't have server.js file and in your package.json you mentioned your start file as server.js and that is not available in your root folder of project.

Comment: i edit the question with the screenshot of the package.json and folder structure.

Comment: Have you try this following step 1.`npm cache clean -f`  2.`npm install -g n` 3.`sudo n latest`.4. `npm start`

Comment: try this step 1:  `npm cache clean --force` step 2: Delete node_modules by `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`  step 3: `npm install` and step 4 `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

Before running `npm start` run `npm install` to install all your modules.

Most probably your project is not installed and the files are not found.

Comment: i already run npm install and i have some warn , but not error .

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the start script specified in your config.json file? You need to write in the scripts section: `"start": "node <your_main_js_file_name>"`.

Answer (score 0):

I can already see that your server.ts is **not in the root** of your folder but in a subfolder. I assume it is going to be **src/ or public/** or whatever so you will have to add that to your script. so for example `"start": "node src/server.ts"`

Comment: currently, it was like this, but I changed it, other members of my team work for them very well.  "start": "node ./build/server.js".I don't know if extension of .js or .ts is the reason. I can't see the build file.But i just take it like this from github of my team.

Comment: Thats weird because I tried it with a typescript project of mine and whenever I remove the path before server.ts where it becomes _"start" : "node server.js"_  I get the exact same error as you showed above. Maybe what you can try is installing nodemon _npm install -D nodemon_ and changing your script to _"start':"nodemon YourSubFolder/server.ts". Fingers crossed